# Finding text with multiple line in a file

Tags: python, regex, findall

I need to extract the fields name between opening and closing round brackets of the unique index  and this can span in 2 or 3 or multiple lines

Here is the content of the file:

```
create index "informix".be_ach_detail_1_ix1 on "informix".be_ach_detail_1 (association,bank_number,batch_date) using btree ; 
create unique index "informix".bank_info_pk on "informix" .bank_info 
(merchant,bank_number,batch_date,sequence_number, association,transaction_code,ach_table) using btree ;
```

Expected output:

(merchant,bank_number,batch_date,sequence_number, association,transaction_code,ach_table)

I have tried multiple `findall` options but it's not working:

```
myfile=re.findall(r'unique index\s.*\S*\)',myfile)[0]
myfile=re.findall(r'unique index\s.*\S*\)',myfile)[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pattern = r"unique index[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)"` which means:

- `unique index` search for exactly this substring in the text
- `[^(]*` match all characters except `(` which will be the text until the bracket opens with `(`
- `\(` the opening bracket (we have to escape the character with a backslash)
- `([^)]*)` the group which matches all characters except `)` which will be the text until the bracket closes with `)`
- `\)` the closing bracket (we have to escape the character with a backslash)

```py
import re

text = """create index "informix".be_ach_detail_1_ix1 on "informix".be_ach_detail_1 (association,bank_number,batch_date) using btree ; create unique index "informix".bank_info_pk on "informix" .bank_info (merchant,bank_number,batch_date,sequence_number, association,transaction_code,ach_table) using btree ;"""

pattern = r"unique index[^(]*\(([^)]*)\)"
print(re.findall(pattern, text))
```

Which prints:

```
['merchant,bank_number,batch_date,sequence_number, association,transaction_code,ach_table']
```